# How to find out what is causing a slow down of the application?

Tags: mysql, performance, apache2

This is not the typical question, but I'm out of ideas and don't know where else to go. If there are better places to ask this, just point me there in the comments. Thanks.

---

### Situation

We have this web application that uses **Zend Framework**, so runs in **PHP** on an **Apache web server**. We use **MySQL** for data storage and **memcached** for object caching.

The application has a very unique usage and load pattern. It is a mobile web application where every full hour a cronjob looks through the database for users that have some information waiting or action to do and sends this information to a (external) notification server, that pushes these notifications to them. After the users get these notifications, the go to the app and use it, mostly for a very short time. An hour later, same thing happens.

### Problem

In the last few weeks usage of the application really started to grow. In the last few days we encountered very high load and doubling of application response times **during and after the sending of these notifications** (so basically every hour). The server doesn't crash or stop responding to requests, it just gets slower and slower and often takes 20 minutes to recover - until the same thing starts again at the full hour.

We have extensive monitoring in place (New Relic, collectd) but I can't figure out what's wrong; I can't find the bottlekneck. That's where you come in:

**Can you help me figure out what's wrong and maybe how to fix it?**

---

### Additional information

The server is a 16 core Intel Xeon (8 cores with hyperthreading, I think) and 12GB RAM running Ubuntu 10.04 (Linux 3.2.4-20120307 x86_64). Apache is 2.2.x and PHP is Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.11.

If any configuration information would help analyze the problem, just comment and I will add it.

### Graphs

#### info

- [phpinfo()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlLl3.gif)
- [apc status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vl4TE.gif)
- [memcache status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcv7K.gif)

#### collectd

- [Processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX0yn.gif)
- [CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjm26.gif)
- [Apache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6SHT.gif)
- [Load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf7NW.gif)
- [MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0ciN.gif)
- [Vmem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3J8D7.gif)
- [Disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QRxJ.gif)

#### New Relic

- **[Application performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4qOl.gif)**
- [Server overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzWtU.gif)
- [Processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrBkd.gif)
- [Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gnBJ.gif)
- [Disks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEHVw.gif)

(Sorry the graphs are gifs and not the same time period, but I think the most important info is in there)

Comment: I think first you should check the mysql connections response when server slows down.. It might be the cause of delay..

Comment: Could define a little bit? I don't really get what you mean or what I have to do to get this.

Comment: [SeaLion](http://sealion.com) would have helped you better in this situation. Raw outputs are always better than graphs for debugging the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly MySQL based. If you look at the final graph mysql/mysql_threads you can see the number of threads hits 200 (which I assume is your setting for max_connections) at 20:00. Once the max_connections has been hit things do tend to take a while to recover.

Using [mtop](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/) to monitor MySQL just before the hour will really help you figure out what is going on but if you cannot install this you could just using `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`. You will need to establish your connection to mysql before the problem hits. You will probably see lots of processes queued with only 1 process currently executing. This will be the most likely culprit.

Having identified the query causing the problems you can attack your code. Without understanding how your application is actually working my best guess would be that using an explicit transaction around the problem query(ies) will probably solve the problem.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for you answer! max_connections actually is 550, so that's not the culprit. But this turned me back to the 'processes' graph. And every time there is a problem the number of processes hits 500. If it is less than 500 on the full hour, the load is not nearly as high. So it seems, we are hitting a limit of open processes. Now I only have to learn how to confirm this...

Comment: And yeah, I will try mtop nonetheless. Problem is I only have limited rights on this server, that's why SHOW PROCESSLIST; is not very usefeul, too, so will have to go the sysadmin route. But looks good.

Comment: Does the notification server access the db as well as the cron process? It might help if you post the code being run by the hourly cron.

Comment: I don't have the code around, but: The hourly cron gets some data from the database fo the users, pushes it off to a server from the external services we use for the notifications, then updates the users that they got a notification. It also runs much shorter than the problems occur (~90 seconds, most of the time used for the http requests).